# Update 2D state array with 2 different strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to search for this in the docs but couldn't find anything

I'm trying to update my array 'myGamesArray' with the string 'query' and 'image'.

This is a multi-dimensional array and I want to update the first column with 'query' and the second column with 'image'.

I tried this here but it did not work:

```js
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Initialization of state
    //films will contain the array of suggestion
    //query will have the input from the autocomplete input
    this.state = {
      myGamesArray:[{name: "", img: ""}],
      games: [],
      query: '  ',
      image: '',
    };
  }



this.setState(prevState => {
const { myGamesArray, query, image } = prevState;
return {
myGamesArray: [...myGamesArray[0][0], query.toString()],
myGamesArray: [...myGamesArray[0][1], image.toString()],
query:''
        };
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the `myGamesArray` once then return it, also spread the prevState so the old values are preserved, so the could should look something like this:

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
    const { myGamesArray, query, image } = prevState;
    myGamesArray.unshift({
        name: query.toString(),
        img: image.toString(),
    });
    return {
      ...prevState
      newGameArray,
      query:'',
    };
  },
```

Comment: I the way that I declaring my 2D array in state correct?. I'm getting an error saying 'undefined is not an object(evaluating 'item[0][0]). This is from I read the value using my flatlist component

Comment: your state is of type array of an object that contains a name and an image, which means it still a 1D array

Comment: If it's able to store 2 values then it's good for me. How to I update name and image with strings?

Comment: you want to add the name and img to the first index of the array?

Comment: if so, use the unshift to push your data to the top of the array, `myGamesArray.unshift({name: query.toString(), img: image.toString()});`

Comment: do I write this under setState()?

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this out

Comment: So this is basically working. The only issue I'm having is that the Flatlist I have is creating an empty card when I load my app because I'm initializing my array of objects as empty

Comment: Is there a way to initialize only when I assign the 2 strings to it? Or initialize in a way that it doesn't see it as a blank object?

Comment: yes, initialize it as empty array `myGamesArray:[],`